# Потеря this в обработчике событий в классе

Tags: javascript, классы, события

Есть два html-элемента и скрипт. В скрипте объявляется класс, который получает один из элементов. У класса есть три метода, первый - функция вращения полученного элемента. Второй метод создает обработчик события keydown, согласно которому он выполняет первый метод класса. Третий метод удаляет этот обработчик события. Я объявляю класс и запускаю второй метод, а третий метод вешаю onclick на кнопку. Но для первого метода происходит потеря this. Как исправить это?

```js
class Rotate {
  constructor(rotateBlock) {
    this.block = rotateBlock;
    this.rotation = 0;
  }
  rotateFunc() {
    this.rotation += 40;
    this.block.style.transform = `rotate(${this.rotation}deg)`;
  }
  startRotate() {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', this.rotateFunc);
  }
  stopRotate() {
    window.removeEventListener('keydown', this.rotateFunc);
  }
}
let rotateBlock = document.querySelector('.block');
let stopBtn = document.querySelector('[name="stopRotate"]');
let rotate = new Rotate(rotateBlock);
rotate.startRotate();
stopBtn.addEventListener('click', rotate.stopRotate);
```

```html
<div class="block">
    F
</div>
<button type="button" name="stopRotate">just stop rotate</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Rotate {
  constructor(rotateBlock) {
    this.block = rotateBlock;
    this.rotation = 0;
    this.rotateHandler = this.rotateFunc.bind(this);
    this.stopHandler = this.stopRotate.bind(this);
  }
  rotateFunc() {
    this.rotation += 40;
    this.block.style.transform = `rotate(${this.rotation}deg)`;
  }
  startRotate() {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', this.rotateHandler);
  }
  stopRotate() {
    window.removeEventListener('keydown', this.rotateHandler);
  }
}
...
stopBtn.addEventListener('click', rotate.stopHandler);
```

Comment: Метод startRotate тоже не работает. он использует this.rotateFunc в котором также используется this. Которое теряется.

Comment: @joestalin14 Уже.

Comment: Отлично, спасибо большое!

Comment: @joestalin14 Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: @Igor теперь все ясно, спасибо!